# "How to make a windows form communicate with Microsoft Office?"

Tags: c#, windows, ms-office

My programs works perfectly with using hotkeys in place to alter text in Microsoft Word, Powerpoint, Excel, and Outlook.

The only problem I have is that the program will not execute unless I either click on it with the mouse or use Alt and Tab to toggle between my program and Microsoft Office programs.

I wish to not use the mouse or use Alt and Tab.  I have a keyboard hook script in place to copy the hotkeys, but it will only work if Windows sees my program on top of everything and is active.

I have my program on top of everything, but when going to Microsoft Word (for example), my program is no longer active and Microsoft Word is now active.  I would have to go to my program to make it active by clicking on it with my mouse or using Alt and Tab, perform the hotkey and then go back to Microsoft Word with using my mouse to click on it or using Alt and Tab to make it active to use the hotkey that was pressed.

With this, how would I go about and make my program a shared plugin for Microsoft Office, to where when it is running, Microsoft Office will recognize my program?

Comment: You might want to consider using Microsoft UI Automation than sending keystrokes.  The latter as you have discovered is kinda flaky

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can automate Outlook form other applications. Due to the fact that Outlook is a singleton only one application instance can be run at the same time on the system. So, you may get a running instance from the ROT:

```
//Get reference to Outlook.Application from the ROT.
oApp =  (Outlook.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application");
```

If there is no Outlook running on the system you may simply create a new one. See [C# app automates Outlook (CSAutomateOutlook)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSAutomateOutlook-a3b7bdc9) for more information.

Comment: I have the reference to Outlook, Word, PowerPoint, and Excel in my form and I have installed and running Outlook, Word, PowerPoint, and Excel on my desktop.  For some reason, Windows 10 Home Addition is choosing not to allow my code to make my program work in junction with the Office programs.  I added my code to this question for you to view.

Comment: All applications must be run under the same security context. Basically, you should run as an administrator all applications if you've run any of them already. Or just without admin permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for you to view so you have an idea what I am doing.
Sorry, I tried to put it as a comment, but it was too long.

```
//MICROSOFT WORD INTEGRATION
        try
        {
            app = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
            app.ActiveWindow.Selection.Font.Color = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColor)(changeColor.R + 0x100 * changeColor.G + 0x10000 * changeColor.B);
        }
        catch (System.Exception excp)
        {

        }
        //MICROSOFT EXCEL INTEGRATION
        try
        {
            xlApp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
            xlBook = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook;
            xlSheet = xlBook.ActiveSheet;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range rngSelection = xlApp.Selection as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range;
            for (var r = 1; r <= rngSelection.Rows.Count; r++)
            {
                for (var c = 1; c <= rngSelection.Columns.Count; c++)
                {
                    rngSelection[r, c].Font.Color = copyProgramText.SelectionColor;
                }
            }

        }
        catch (System.Exception excp)
        {

        }
        //MICROSOFT POWERPOINT INTEGRATION
        try
        {
            pwptApp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("PowerPoint.Application");
            pwptApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(changeColor);
            if (pwptApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Text.Trim() == "") pwptApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Text = " ";
        }
        catch (System.Exception excp)
        {

        }
        //MICROSOFT OUTLOOK INTEGRATION
        try
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application otlkApp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application");
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Explorer otlkExp = otlkApp.ActiveExplorer();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Selection otlkSel = otlkExp.Selection;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem otlkMsg = otlkApp.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector insp = otlkMsg.GetInspector;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document otlkDoc = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document)insp.WordEditor;

            string sepSel = otlkDoc.Application.Selection.Text;
            byte rColor = changeColor.R;
            byte gColor = changeColor.G;
            byte bColor = changeColor.B;
            if (sepSel.Trim() == "\r") return;
            char cReturn = (char)13;
            if (sepSel == cReturn.ToString()) return;
            if (sepSel != "")
            {
                otlkMsg.HTMLBody = otlkMsg.HTMLBody.Replace(sepSel, "<font style = 'color: rgb(" + rColor.ToString() + ", " + gColor.ToString() + ", " + bColor.ToString() + ")'>" + sepSel + " </font>");
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

            prevOutlookContents = otlkMsg.HTMLBody;

        }
        catch (System.Exception excp)
        {

        }
```